# Using R to get random samples matching a given sample with respect to one parameter

Tags: r, matching, random

I have a set G (e.g. of genes) from which I would like to choose a sample S of size n so that the distribution of a parameter p (e.g. expression level) of the elements in S matches the distribution of p in another (given) sample S1 (also of size n). Is there a simple way to achieve that with R? I've seen, there is a package "matching", which is probably quite what I need, but the documentation is rather sparse. Could someone maybe give a hint how I should do this?

Any help would be appreciated,

mce

Some test data:

```
G <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC", "geneD", "geneE", "geneF", "geneG", "geneH", "geneI", "geneJ", "geneK", "geneL"), RPKM=c(0.0409863535590667, 5.22343174185167, 20.075922041625, 7.383144214709, 22.4389644984, 51.9789100011863, 25.0677263296667, 22.1918649645167, 0.0146442973768667, 0.5335993060184, 7.65882673982233, 0.0121380062032333))

S1 <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneX", "geneY", "geneZ"), RPKM=c(3.32943395267333, 0.0049997324803, 31.59458677743))
```

n = 3

Comment: See *sampling* package

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. What does RPKM mean? What do you mean by "S matches the distribution of p"? E.g. in your two test data frames, there is no overlap in the gene symbols.

Comment: @Sean: RPKM is the expression measure, i.e. corresponds to parameter p in the above. What I want is to take a sample S of size n = 3 from G such that mean and sd of RPKM in S match the mean and sd of RPKM in S1 reasonably well.

Comment: The sampling package indeed provides a good solution. Thanks a lot, mce.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the sampling package is of use here....

Comment: @Ananda Mahto: Thanks for your interest. After some more reading you may be right. The sampling package provides a way to make the sample S match the population G (as far as I get it) but not match a second sample S1. At least it is not obvious how to do that to me yet. But it must be quite a common problem, e.g. finding an age-matched control group for a given group in medicine etc. Do you have any idea how to proceed? Any suggestions welcome.